# Have the LQP and NAA flags been separated?

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts

I flagged an answer as Low Quality earlier today. It was edited out thanks to <s>Help & Improvement</s> Triage.

To my astonishment, I could still raise a NAA flag, which was not possible previously.

[image: NAA and LQP. Together forever?]

Is this a new feature?

Comment: It is A/Bug test ...

Comment: If a VLQ/NAA flag is marked helpful, you have the option to flag the post as {remaining type of flag, VLQ/NAA}. The new here is if a VLQ/NAA flag is retracted, you *still* have the option to flag the post as {remaining type of flag, VLQ/NAA}.

Comment: @rene is this when you test a bug on your users?